# Snow Leopard and XCode 3.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, osx-snow-leopard

My Original Leopard's XCode installation works fine (for iPhone 3.0 Development) with Snow Leopard without making any changes.

What are the benefits I'll get if I install XCode 3.2 that comes with the SL DVD?

Is it mandatory to upgrade?

Comment: I've upgraded now... Didn't face any problems so far. Able to get my app on iPhone as well.

Comment: Could you "unaccept" my answer please?  It was from docs I found at Apple, but since others have reported differently, I don't want mine to look authoritative in any way.

Comment: Some nice upgrade coverage at TUAW: http://www.tuaw.com/2009/09/03/xcode-3-2-daily-tip-upgrading-xcode/

Answer (score 8):

Xcode 3.1 is NOT supported on Snow Leopard. It might work, though there are several known bugs, per Chris Espinosa from Apple's tools team.

Apple only supports Xcode tools 3.2 on Snow Leopard.

In terms of features, my favorites are the integration with Clang/LLVM, Instruments upgrades (major), the new doco system and general improvements to the editor. I can't imagine why you wouldn't upgrade.

Also keep in mind that you need to download and install the Snow Leopard version of the iPhone SDK once you upgrade to Xcode 3.2. That is basically the same as the Leopard version, though it uses a version of Foundation that is closer to the actual iPhone - this is to reduce issues where a class works in the Simulator but not on the device.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I would be very surprised if Apple supported submitting iPhone apps for the App Store built with 3.1 on Snow Leopard. They want you on 3.2 if you're on SL.

Comment: I upgraded to Snow Leopard after WWDC just to have access to Xcode 3.2, it's that much of a step forward.  I've submitted three updates to my iPhone applications since, and all have gone off without a hitch.  One thing to be aware of is that it's possible to build toward iPhone OS 2.x, but it's difficult to do on Snow Leopard and officially unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 3.1 should continue to work fine but is not supported.  The upgrade contains a bunch of bug fixes and some new features.  Since you're a developer, I'm guessing you have access to the Apple Developer Connection site ... here are the release notes for Xcode 3.2:
      [About Xcode Developer Tools](http://developer.apple.com/mac/scripts/downloader.php?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2/about_xcode_3.2.pdf)

Personally, I didn't see anything earthshattering in the release, but I upgraded anyway.  The biggest line items were about static code analysis.  I'm always interested in the bug fixes though.  Plus Apple has tested all the latest stuff as a group -- and I don't want to tempt fate by mix 'n match.

Comment: Static analysis alone is worth the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for gravedigging here, but I can't understand how you get used to the new back/forward navigation. It sucks. Now I never know where the cursor will go to when I press those. I want to quickly change between two/three sourcefiles, but now I have to use my mouse instead because of Apple's "interesting locations" in the source. I just pressed back three times and I'm still on the same line. Wow, interesting locations I must say.. I'm so dissapointed since this have decreased my tempo so incredible much that I'm seriously thinking of switching back to 3.1 (and Leopard if that is required). Every time I mention this to other Xcode users they answer "just click this and that", why would I want to use my mouse when coding ? I hate using the mouse when coding.
And by the way, doesn't pageup/down move the cursor anymore, just the "view" ?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded and was upset to see that I now need to be connected to the internet to use the documentation. (Of course that may have been the case before and I didn't notice.)

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the Core Data designer with Snow Leo and Xcode 3.1. After the update on 3.2 all was fine again.